# Separating map and polyline initialization

Tags: google-maps

I'm using the following code to draw a polyline on Google map. I want to initialize the map in a separate function and draw polyline in another. When I put their codes in separate functions, things don't work for me. Can anyone tell me how to separate polyline and map initialization?

```
function initialize() {
     var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
  };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);  

      var flightPlanCoordinates = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
    new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)
  ];
  var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
flightPath.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: What issue are you having doing that?  The `map` variable needs to be accessible when you initialize the polyline, one option to address that is to make it global (currently it is local to the `initialize` function).

Answer (score 0):

You may separate out the code for drawing polyline and call this function from idle listener registered during map initialization.